# Regex, extract var inside interval

Tags: regex, msdn, dngrep

i have a doubt about the REGEX (Regular Expression) by Microsoft. I have a log file write in this mode.

```
2017-02-20 15:58:45.442 - [XYZ] 155 RADIO_TRAIN_TO_TRACK_INITIATION_COM_SESSION
                                  .VAR1
                                  .VAR2
                                  .VAR3
                                  .VAR4
2017-02-20 15:58:46.432 - [XYZ]   32 RADIO_TRACK_TO_TRAIN_CONFIGURATION_DETERMINATION
                                  .VAR1
                                  .VAR2
                                  .VAR3
                                  .VAR4
                                  .VAR5
                                  .VAR6
2017-02-20 15:58:48.541 - [XYZ] 155 RADIO_TRAIN_TO_TRACK_INITIATION_COM_SESSION
other lines
```

My question is: How i can extract all text from 15:58:45 to 15:58:46 (include). (Using regex).

I use `15:58:4[5-6]|VAR1` expression but this expression extract all VAR1 in the log, i would extract only VAR1 inside a specific range.

Regards

Comment: `|` = `or` in regex

Comment: Yes i know, in fact my expression is wrong. Do you have any suggestion?

Comment: Try `\b15:58:4[5-6].*(?:\r?\n(?!\d{4}-\d{2}-\d).*)*`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Thank you, your expression extract only the the timestamp from log. i would extract all text inside this time

Comment: Not sure what you mean, [have a look here](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=15%3a58%3a4%5b5-6%5d.*%28%3f%3a%5cr%3f%5cn%28%3f!%5cd%7b4%7d-%5cd%7b2%7d-%5cd%29.*%29*&i=2017-02-20+15%3a58%3a45.442+-+%5bXYZ%5d+155+RADIO_TRAIN_TO_TRACK_INITIATION_COM_SESSION%0d%0a++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.VAR1%0d%0a++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.VAR4%0d%0a2017-02-20+15%3a58%3a46.432+-+%5bXYZ%5d+++32+RADIO_TRACK_TO_TRAIN_CONFIGURATION_DETERMINATION%0d%0a++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.VAR3%0d%0a++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.VAR6%0d%0a2017-02-20+15%3a58%3a48.541+-+%5bXYZ%5d+155+)

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew ok, i use dnGrep [link](http://dngrep.github.io/). in this program your expression doesn't work

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew sorry for the inconvenience, can you help me with this example? [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43230296/regex-search-with-and-operator)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use

```
\b15:58:4[5-6].*(?:\r?\n(?!\d{4}-\d{2}-\d).*)*
```

Note that `Multiline` check box is **ON**.

**Details**:

- `\b` - a word boundary
- `15:58:4`  - a sequence of literal chars
- `[5-6]` - either `5`or `6`
- `.*` - the rest of the line
- `(?:\r?\n(?!\d{4}-\d{2}-\d).*)*` -  0+ sequences of:

  - `\r?\n(?!\d{4}-\d{2}-\d)` -  a line break (CRLF or LF) not followed with 4 digits, `-`, 2 digits, `-` and a digit
  - `.*` - the rest of the line.

[image]

Or  the same pattern but a bit shorter and less efficient, but potentially more readable:

```
\b15:58:4[5-6].*?(?=\d{4}-\d{2}-\d|$)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much. This is great. But the last question. How can i extract only var1? (Inside this range)

Comment: Try `(?<=\b15:58:4[5-6](?:(?!\n\d{4}-\d{2}-\d).)*?\n {3,}\.)VAR\d+`

Comment: It's great! Thank you. Thank you also details. Sorry for the last question, if i want a VAR1 "AND" (And operator) VAR2?

Comment: Hi, I was away. I cannot understand what you mean  by `VAR1 AND VAR2`.

Comment: Hi Wiktor, thank you for the reply. I would understand how select var1 and var2 inside a specific range. (And operator as && in C language). For example, how can select var 1 and var 2 inside range 15:58:4[5-6].

Comment: There is no `AND` operator in regex. If you want to match from `A` to `B`, make sure you match the allowed chars in between them.

Comment: Sure, i know that there is no 'AND' operator in regex. But if i would match two variables (for example 'ID','TRAIN') inside the same interval (15:58:4[5-6]). How can do it? Thank you so much

Comment: Like [this](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%3f%3c%3d%5cb15%3a58%3a4%5b5-6%5d%28%3f%3a%28%3f!%5cn%5cd%7b4%7d-%5cd%7b2%7d-%5cd%29.%29*%3f%5cn+%7b3%2c%7d%5c.%29%28ID%7cTRAIN%29&i=2017-02-20+15%3a58%3a45.442+155+SESSION%0d%0a+++++.ID%0d%0a+++++.VAR2%0d%0a+++++.TRAIN%0d%0a2017-02-20+15%3a58%3a46.432+32+D%0d%0a+++++.VAR1%0d%0a+++++.TRAIN%0d%0a+++++.VAR3%0d%0a+++++.ID%0d%0a2017-02-20+15%3a58%3a48.541+-+%5bXYZ%5d+155%0d%0a_SESSION%0d%0aother+lines&o=s)?

Comment: Yes, in regex tester run ok. But it don't run inside dnGrep app. Do you have any suggestion? Thank you

Comment: yes, i don't check "Dot as newline" option. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can use a regex trick like this:

```
(15:58:45[\s\S]*?15:58:46)
```

**[Working demo](https://regex101.com/r/xlUDRs/1)**

Or also using the `s` single line flag

```
(?s)(15:58:45.*?15:58:46)
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply, i use this program [dnGREP] (http://dngrep.github.io/), but these formulas don't work inside it

Comment: @nonac, I think that app might be using a process by line feature (multiline), if so.. you won't be able to achieve what you want with that tool. Check if you can disable that feature